# power series, uknown substitution of $-1$

Tags: polynomials, power-series, quadrature

This time I type my problem into LaTeX, but to show the problem I'll also include the appropriate snippet:

I do not understand in the book by [Ralston: A first course in numerical analysis](http://62.182.86.140/main/903000/4bb55429c193eb542401a75bdd262d18/%28International%20series%20in%20pure%20and%20applied%20mathematics%29%20Anthony%20Ralston_%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20A%20first%20course%20in%20numerical%20analysis-McGraw-Hill%20%20%281978%29.pdf) $(4.10-28)$ why

$$\Sigma_{j=0}^m |c_{mj}|=t_m(-1):$$

I would understand it if $c_{mj}$ alternate their signs,starting with positive for $j=0$, but I do not know why this is the case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is, if $x_1,...,x_n$ are positive real numbers and
$$
p(z)=\sum c_kz^k=(x_1-z)(x_2-z)...(x_n-z),
$$
if then the coefficient sequence is alternating. This is quite easy to see, as in the expansion of
$$
p(-z)=\sum c_k(-1)^kz^k=(x_1+z)(x_2+z)...(x_n+z)
$$
all coefficients are positive.

Comment: Right! Have you thought about which book may I read in succession of Ralston, which is as good as that but more modern ? One or two hints will do. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Lutz, I've started a [bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610121/algebraic-equivalent-interpolation-formulae). Please, consider replying.